# How do i map fields based on a condition when using the Azure DevOps Migration Tools?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

I have a custom field on my Azure DevOps user stories that maps directly to the same custom field on the target project. However i want to be able to fill it with data from another field in case the custom field is empty on the source, like this:

- if Field A on Source is "ABC" then Field A on Target would be "ABC".
- if Field A on Source is "" then Field A on Target would get its value from Field B.

How do i achieve this? I tried using the MultiValueConditionalMapConfig but i can't find any examples online so i have no idea how it works and trial and error was fruitless. The documentation doesn't explain how this specific mapping works so asking here was my only option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is `MultiValueConditionalMapConfig`  sample:

```
  "FieldMaps": [
    {
      "$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2"
      },
      "targetFieldsAndValues": {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2"
      }
    }
   ]
```

> if Field A on Source is "" then Field A on Target would get its value from Field B

However, I’m afraid that there is no supported condition expression in serval `FieldMap` from the `configuration.json` sample file.Please refer to doc:[Getting started with VSTS sync Migrator](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/getting-started)

About `FieldMaps` refer to :[Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/)

You can discuss in this website:[migration discussions](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/discussions) for more detailed information.

Comment: @sonicadv27 Hi, Does it give you some help?